# fetching from twitter Api

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

Please i need help on how to fetch data from twitter api for a week.
i'm using nodeJs to write the code and it doesn't seem to work well.

I'm using the twit module in nodeJs btw.

```
var today = new Date();
 var day = today.getDate();
 var month = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
 var year = today.getFullYear();

let months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

 for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     if (day > 0) {
         day--;
     }
     if (day == 0) {
         month = month - 1;
         day = months[month - 1];
     }
     console.log(day, month, year);
 }
    let params = {
                   q: `to:${firstBrand} since:${year}-${month}-${day-1} until:${year}-${month}-${currentDay}`,
                   count: 5000,
                   language: 'en',
                   entities: false
               };
               let param = {
                   q: `to:${secondBrand} since:${year}-${month}-${day-1} until:${year}-${month}-${currentDay}`,
                   count: 5000,
                   language: 'en',
                   entities: false
               };

               t.get('search/tweets', params, dataGotten);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your setup is done correctly:

```
const Twit = require('twit')

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '...',
  consumer_secret:      '...',
  access_token:         '...',
  access_token_secret:  '...',
  timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests. 
});
```

I would try this:

```
t.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

By the way, `params` is optional argument, so first of all try how it works without them:

```
t.get('search/tweets', function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: i already did all this, i just dont know how to get daily counts. thats all i need

Comment: @AlameenIpaye so you are able to receive tweets?

Comment: It sounds like you need to just loop through the returned JSON data and count the number of Tweets in the response? Here's an example using twurl and jq -> https://gist.github.com/andypiper/32bdb4c7f0b8d65385fc7c8fa3988083#file-count-search-results-md

Comment: @Lazyexpert i was able to receive tweets.